# Expressing as a composite function to begin differentiating with the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm trying to differentiate $y=(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3$ using the chain rule, but I am having trouble writing it as a composite function. Any help would be great as I can finish the problem on my own once I just get started in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it first as a product of $x+1$ and $(x+2)^2(x+3)^3$; differentiating that is going to give you

$$(x+1)\Big((x+2)^2(x+3)^3\Big)'+1\cdot(x+2)^2(x+3)^3\;.$$

Now you have to differentiate $(x+2)^2(x+3)^3$; that’s another product, of $(x+2)^2$ and $(x+3)^3$. It’s only when you differentiate the powers $(x+2)^2$ and $(x+3)^3$ that you really have to invoke the chain rule.

Comment: @wadetaylor: You’re welcome!

Comment: Is there a rule for differentiating multiple products or do you have to write them as a composition of functions?

Comment: @wadetaylor: There is, and it can be proved by mathematical induction. In the case of three factors you get $(uvw)'=u'vw+uv'w+uvw'$, and it generalizes to larger number of factors in the obvious way.

Comment: @wadetaylor Have you heard of Logarithmic differentiation? For a function that consists of multiple products and division, Logarithmic differentiation can make things a lot easier...

Comment: I have never done logarithmic differentiation before. I am studying calculus again after studying it previously two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule alone won't cut it here. You need the rule for differentiating products, i.e. $(f\cdot g)' = f'g + fg'$. Then, first set

$$f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)^2\\
g(x)=(x+3)^3$$

and you can use the chain rule to calculate $g'$, while for $f'$, you need the product rule again.

Answer (score 0):

When you have products such as $$y=(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3$$ logarithmic differentiation makes life simpler $$\log(y)=\log(x+1)+2\log(x+2)+3\log(x+3)$$ Differentiating $$\frac{y'}y=\frac 1{x+1}+\frac 2{x+2}+\frac 3{x+1}=\frac {6 x^2+22 x+18 }{(x+1) (x+2) (x+3)}$$ Multiply both sides by $y$ to get $$y'=\frac {6 x^2+22 x+18 }{(x+1) (x+2) (x+3)}(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3=(6 x^2+22 x+18)(x+2)(x+3)^2$$

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try!

Comment: You are very welcome ! This is a classical, simple and efficient way when you want to differentiate products or quotients in which the terms can be raised to any powers. Try and have fun !